# Test Laravel Service Provider with phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to test my Authentication Service Provider in phpunit. The code in provider is:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
    }
    public function boot() {
        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return new User("some params");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Currently I have mocked the instance of Application::class and can test if the register and boot methods are called but now I need to test the code inside viaRequest method. I tried doing the following:

```
class AuthServiceProviderTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $app_mock;
    protected $provider;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->setUpMocks();
        $this->provider = new AuthServiceProvider($this->app_mock);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    private function setUpMocks(){
        $this->app_mock = \Mockery::mock(Application::class);
    }

    public function testIfProviderIsConstructed(){
        $this->assertInstanceOf(AuthServiceProvider::class, $this->provider);
    }

    public function testIfviaRequestIsCalled(){
        $this->app_mock->shouldReceive("viaRequest")
            ->once();

        $this->provider->boot();
    }

}
```

But got an error:

```
Error : Cannot use object of type Mockery_0_Illuminate_Contracts_Foundation_Application as array
```

Could you advice how I should test the viaRequest method?

Comment: Did my answer help your problem or do you have any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, they are using array indexes on the mock which it can't.

I'm guessing that you would be able to parse an array instead and get the desired functionality.

```
$this->provider = new AuthServiceProvider(['auth' => $this->app_mock]);
```

Comment: This is a very unique question, my solution is kinda hacky, but let see if we can make it work.